# Connecting stereo to laptop audio output gives humming noise

Tags: laptop, audio, windows-10, speakers

When I connect my stereo to my laptop (Acer Aspire 5750G, running windows 10 x64), I get a very loud humming noise from the stereo.
But here are the different scenario's and the effect on the humming noise, in all the cases, it doesn't matter if the laptop charger is plugged in or not.

1)Normal:
 (Just plug stereo in and listen to music): Very loud humming noise.

2)By right clicking the speaker icon in the taskbar on the right side, and clicking recording devices:
 The humming volume lowers. But only when in the tab "record".

3) When I plug in my erabuds instead of the stereo, no humming occurs.

4)Put a Y-splitter in the audio output, and in 1 hole, you put the cable to the stereo. In the other hole, you put earbuds. In this case the humming disapears or lowers significally.

5) No humming ever occurs when the audio ouput is not used.

Could somebody guide in the right direction how to solve this, because exams are coming up and I need my good music ;)

PS: I didn't have this problem when running windows 7, but I don't really want to roll back to windows 7.

Comment: Best guess - plug/socket mismatch. The humming is a ground loop. The earbuds & cable to your stereo have a different number of silver bands on the plug [or worse still, the same number of bands but a different configuration, which is really hard to tell by looking. Sony used to be bad for doing that]. One is right, the other is wrong for the socket. Get one that matches.

Comment: I think that if the laptop is on battery (and not plugged into wall socket) then you do not have a ground loop. Can you specify what inputs on the stereo you are using? Note that you have two amplifiers in series here, so you want the laptop volume high so that the music (signal) is louder than any noise that the lapiop amplifier produces. This way the stereo volume will be lower and it will not amplify the noise.

Comment: The cables used to match, the problem started occuring when i installed Windows 10. (I also moved the stereo, stereo is JVC MX-J35R BTW, old stereo system)
The stereo uses to AUX-input (RCA, red and white, so i use a cable that goes from a male 3.5 mm to RCA red and white)
The volume on the laptop is at its max, but the humming volume does not change with the laptop volume, only with the stereo volume.

Comment: The humming may not be due to a ground loop, but simply from a bad ground connection.  If you try hot-plugging an audio channel's RCA plug, you will typically hear a hum when the RCA's center tip makes contact with the jack.  But the hum disappears when the outer sleeve makes contact to establish proper ground.

Comment: I suspect there is no fault in the connection, because when plug in my cell phone instead of my pc, I get very clear music. When I plug in my earbuds, I also get very clear sound. So I suspect there is a software problem?